# Is the multiplicative group $\{-1,1\}$ isomorphic with $\{0,1\}$?

Tags: group-theory, inverse

In my opinions of a math ignoramus, $\{0,1\}$ is not a multiplicative group since $0$ has no inverse.

The above was written by a Reviewer. If I am right, how to "prove" that $\{0,1\}$ is not a multiplicative group?

Comment: Do you know the group axioms?

Answer (score 6):

A set is not a group. A set with a closed binary operation is a group (or at the very least, it might be a group; there are some requirements).

The set $\{1,-1\}$ equipped with (standard) multiplication is a group. The set $\{0,1\}$ equipped with modulo-2 addition is a group. These two groups are isomorphic.

$\{0,1\}$ equipped with multiplication is *not* a group, as it doesn't fulfill the required properties. There are three of these properties, it's not difficult to find the one it violates.

Comment: I usually think of *four* properties:  closure, associative, identity, and inverse

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I usually think closure is placed one level above the other three. A closed binary operation on a set makes a group if it fulfills the other three. But to each their own.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are considering $\{0,1\}$ as a group with the operation of addition mod $2$ (i.e. isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$).

In that case the answer is yes, check that $f : \{-1,1\} \to \{0,1\}$ given by $f(x)=\frac12(1-x)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: what about $f(x)=\dfrac{\ln x}{i\pi}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Is that function different in any way?

Comment: may make isomorphism more apparent

Answer (score 0):

As *sets*, $\{-1,1\}$ and $\{0,1\}$ are isomorphic to each other - that is, they have the same cardinality ($2$). In the category (or 'universe') of sets, isomorphisms take the form of bijective functions. In order for two groups to be isomorphic, the underlying sets must have the same cardinality - so there is at least *a* group $(G,*)$ with $G=\{0,1\}$ such that $(G,*)\cong (\{-1,1\},\times)$.

That said, you need to specify the operation '$*$' to determine whether or not a particular group $(\{0,1\},*)$ is isomorphic to the multiplicative group $(\{-1,1\},\times)$. As stated by others, $\{0,1\}$ does *not* form a group under the usual multiplication operation.

To prove that $(\{0,1\},\times)$ is not a [multiplicative] group, you need to show that at least one of the [group axioms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Group.html) fails.

If, for some *other* operation $*$ (for example, addition modulo 2), $(\{-1,1\},*)$ is a group, then it suffices to show that there is a bijective homomorphism $f:\{-1,1\}\to\{0,1\}$ - i.e...

$$\forall a,b\in\{-1,1\}.f(a\times b)=f(a)*f(b)$$

...for this group to be isomorphic to $(\{-1,1\},\times)$.

**Edit:**

The group $(\{-1,1\},\times)$ is isomorphic to the group $(\{0,1\}, \oplus)$, where $a\oplus b = (a + b)\mod2$ (this is the same as `a + b % 2`). This means that there is an *isomorphism* $f$ between $(\{-1,1\},\times)$ and $(\{0,1\}, \oplus)$.

Check:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(1-x)\implies f^{-1}(x)=1-2x$$

$f:\{-1,1\}\to\{0,1\}$ is a *bijection*

$$f(-1\times-1)=f(-1)\oplus f(-1)=0$$

$$f(-1\times 1)=f(-1)\oplus f(1)=1$$

$$f(1\times 1)=f(1)\oplus f(1)=0$$

$f:\{-1,1\}\to\{0,1\}$ is a *homomorphism*

$f(x)$ is a *bijective homomorphism*, therefore $f$ is an *isomorphism*

Comment: This issue is of a fundamental importance. Why?

Comment: Say, that {-1, 1} as a multiplicative group is isomorphic with {0, 1} as a additive group (it was questioned that it cannot be since 1+1 is not in a group), one can claim that computers, currently based on 0-1, could be working equally well if they are based on {-1, 1} as a multiplicative group}.

Comment: Regretfully, I am not a mathematician but I am a rather achieved researcher in computing and will tell you that electronic construction of a computer based on {-1, 1} would be a great mistake.

Comment: any help will be of great help.

Comment: I have asked for help since one publication tries to redefine https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio (the most celebrated ratio is $\pi$). Ratio survived it its original form for well over 2,000 yrs. In my opinion,it should stay this way.

Comment: @JanTamariani Okay, there's a bit to unpack here. First off, I've added an explanation of the particular isomorphism between the multiplicative group $(\{-1,1\},\times)$ and the additive group $(\{0,1\},\oplus)$. As you can see, $1\oplus 1$ is in the additive group, but this is addition *modulo 2*, not standard addition (i.e. $1\oplus 1=0\neq 2$). As for $\{-1,1\}$ being used in place of binary for computation, there is no difference. $0$ and $1$ are just labels for the physical state of bit. Any two symbols can be swapped for '$0$' and '$1$' without changing anything but the name.

Comment: @JanTamariani The importance of isomorphisms, in general, is that two isomorphic structures may be used in place of one another by simply 'relabeling' things. This is especially significant when one structure is *easier* to work with than the other. *Specific* isomorphisms are no more significant than the structures involved.

Comment: @JanTamariani I am not sure what any of this has to do with ratios. Could you please clarify? If you have a question about a definition in a particular publication, it would be best to post a link to that publication and ask for clarification or explanation of the part you are confused about.

Comment: My PhD supervisor (listed in Wikipedia; has well over 165 entries in MathReviews) claims that there is no order in $Z_2$. It makes sense to me if 1+1=0 in $Z_2$. Your confirmation of it is of great importance.

Comment: @JanTamariani What do you mean by "order"?